# How to send multiple asynchronous requests with url caching?

Tags: java, multithreading, okhttp

So I am aware of multithreading using `Executors` from Java, and I can simply make multiple `Callable` with an http-client (e.g. okhttp) and different urls.

But now some of the urls might be repeated, and I want to use sort of in-memory cache to avoid repeating url requests. Would `ConcurrentMap` be useful in this scenario?

I am also aware libraries such as `okhttp` provides [cache](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching), but I think it uses disk instead of in-memory.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider either Guava’s CacheBuilder or Android’s LruCache. Both automatically deduplicate concurrent requests.